# Reliable file transfer

Tags: file-transfer

I have a big gzipped file which is 2.5G in size, I tried scp it from the remote server, after the transfer has finished, I md5sum checked it, it failed. The transfer was completed and the file size(in bytes) are exactly the same.

My question is how can I transfer this file reliably with scp or with any other tool?

Thanks.

Comment: Please improve your question with any other information you might have, i.e., if you are sure that the transfer completed, are the file sizes identical? What are the source and target operating systems and file systems? What kind of access do you have on the remote host? Can you run `rsync` or a simple web server there (via Python, perhaps) to then get the file with `wget` or `curl`?

Answer (score 2):

rsync will do its best to make sure that the file transferred is intact, provided you don't override its normal behavior.

Comment: Does -e option count as 'override normal behavoir'?

Comment: Nope. rsync isn't that concerned about the transport. As long as it can talk to rsync on the other side, it's all good.

Comment: Do you mean an rsync server on the remote? I don't have one but it looks running fine.

Comment: rsync running on the local system opens a shell on the remote system and runs rsync there, and then the two instances of rsync communicate over the link.

Comment: Turns out rsync isn't reliable either, I downloaded a couple of large files with rsync, some were fine some were not.

Comment: How are you verifying the files?

Answer (score 0):

Bittorent, DirectConnect clients also verify checksums on transfer and **re-transfer broken blocks**